# Reports in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, report, google-analytics-4

I have a custom event called campus that I send from my app developed in Flutter, a parameter called card with a string value, I need to see a historical report of the values ​​of the card parameter in the campus event

Currently I can see that report "number of events by event name", but in real time, I need to see it historically

[image]

I would appreciate your guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use GA4 Explore reports, you can find this area in the left menu in GA4 UI.
More info about it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: @kei - I will add to this answer...make sure you have setup the custom parameters or they will not be available in the Explorer reports.